# JavaScript. Мгновенная печать

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Возможно сделать так, что при открытии html файла, он сразу выводился на печать (в PDF) без данного окна? (изображение ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Если такое не совсем возможно сделать, то как можно сделать, чтобы, выводилось сразу окно куда сохранять файл (в формате PDF) при нажатии на кнопку?*

Comment: Можно формировать pdf на сервере и просто редиректить на него с клиента. Не встречал нормальных клиентских pdf-библиотек..

Comment: @vp_arth, да я слышал о таком методе, но проблема в том, что у меня никакого сервера нет и сам сервер будет лишним, по этому искал ответ более классическим способом... Просто в браузерах-то есть этот конвертер, а как его использовать в коде (для автоматизации) никто не знает

Comment: @ElemStack, не во всех он есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске хрома надо ему указать флаги: `--kiosk --kiosk-printing`, а предвариательно настроить в качестве дефаултного принтера печать в pdf.

Список всех флагов: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: а как это возможно сделать кодом? 
к примеру: window.open("2.html",--kiosk --kiosk-printing ); ?

Comment: @ElemStack, нельзя, конечно.